# How to do word count in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table `table_a` like

```
query
------
apple
no fruit
this is 
not a number
```

I want to write hive query to get word count based on space like

```
query           count
------      ------------
apple           1
no fruit        2
this is         2
not a  number   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to split to an array and count the elements:

```
select t.*, size(split(query, ' '))
```

If you want to count multiple spaces as a single delimiter:

```
select t.*, size(split(query, '[ ]+'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the column contents, e.g.

```
select  *
       ,size(split(query, '[\\s]+'))  as count
from table_a
```

Using the the whitespace `\s` shorthand character allows you not only to ignore multiple spaces but also tabs and alike.